# CMake add_subdirectory given source which is not an existing directory

Tags: android, c++, firebase, cmake

I'm following [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cpp/setup?platform=android#android) tutorial in order to implement firebase in my android project using C++. I've followed all the steps as the tutorial shows, but when I run my project, I'm getting this error message:

```
 CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:46 (add_subdirectory):
    add_subdirectory given source "olympic/firebase_cpp_sdk" which is not an
    existing directory.
```

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
# For more information about using CMake with Android Studio, read the
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        native-lib

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        native-lib.cpp)

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
        log-lib

        # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
        # you want CMake to locate.
        log)

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        native-lib

        # Links the target library to the log library
        # included in the NDK.
        ${log-lib})
# Add Firebase libraries to the target using the function from the SDK.
add_subdirectory(${FIREBASE_CPP_SDK_DIR} bin/ EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)


# The core Firebase library (firebase_app) is required to use any Firebase product,
# and it must always be listed last.
set(firebase_libs firebase_analytics firebase_app)
target_link_libraries(${target_name} "${firebase_libs}")
```

**Build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.10.2"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.deltadna.android:deltadna-sdk:4.11.3.1'
    implementation 'com.helpshift:android-helpshift-aar:7.+'
    implementation "com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:5.+"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android.defaultConfig.externalNativeBuild.cmake {
    arguments "-DFIREBASE_CPP_SDK_DIR=$gradle.firebase_cpp_sdk_dir"
}

apply from: "firebase_cpp_sdk/Android/firebase_dependencies.gradle"
firebaseCpp.dependencies {
    analytics
}
```

Comment: That tutorial says: `systemProp.firebase_cpp_sdk.dir=full-path-to-SDK`, but `olympic/firebase_cpp_sdk` doesn't look like a full path to me...

Comment: @Frank now that I've put the full path I'm getting the following error: "Cannot specify link libraries for target "firebase_analytics;firebase_app"
  which is not built by this project."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error complains that the directory `olympic/firebase_cpp_sdk` does not exist. From the documentation for [`add_subdirectory()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_subdirectory.html), the first argument to this command can be a relative or absolute path:

> If it is a relative path it will be evaluated with respect to the current directory (the typical usage), but it may also be an absolute path.

Since you have provided a relative path, CMake will look for `olympic/firebase_cpp_sdk` *relative to the current CMakeLists.txt file* being processed; this path does not exist on your system. To ensure CMake can locate the `firebase_cpp_sdk` directory, try specifying an **absolute** path instead, as suggested in the tutorial in this step:

> 2. Specify the location of the unzipped SDK in your project's gradle.properties file:
>
>    ```
>     systemProp.firebase_cpp_sdk.dir=full-path-to-SDK
>    ```

So try the full path:

```
systemProp.firebase_cpp_sdk.dir=/your/full/path/to/SDK
```

Comment: It seems that is working now, thanks, but I'm getting the following error:
Cannot specify link libraries for target "firebase_analytics;firebase_app"
  which is not built by this project.

Comment: @AND4011002849 Glad it's working! That is a separate issue, which suggests that you have not pointed to the *top-level* CMake file in the firebase SDK package, or that something else went wrong in the firebase CMake configuration. It may help to clear your CMake cache and run CMake from scratch, after the path change you made as described in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify path to the "firebase sdk" before:

```
# Add Firebase libraries to the target using the function from the SDK.
add_subdirectory(${FIREBASE_CPP_SDK_DIR} bin/ EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
```

and then set this path to the cmake variable "FIREBASE_CPP_SDK_DIR":

```
set(FIREBASE_CPP_SDK_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/<some relative path inside of your project>")
```

where `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` - path where located current CMakeLists.txt.